# Automatically create GMail filters based on externally hosted word list

Tags: gmail

I'd like to easily import a word list, hosted on Github, to GMail as archive filters. Then later re-run this process to update the list.

The goal is to provide blacklists against common known Finnish spammers.

Possible options I have considered

- Bookmarklet
- Using GMail API
- Creating GMail Labs extension (or whatever they are called)

What kind API options I have for maintaining GMail filter list? Programming language does not matter.

Optionally this would be a single click / single command operation e.g. from terminal or browser bookmark.

Comment: I want to forward mails that suck, to myself at eg jchris+ban@gmail.com and have the original sender go skip the inbox from then on.

Answer (score 2):

Today I was curious about this myself, although for a different reason... I found this info and thought I'd risk a bit of necromancy :)

You should take a look at [Gmail settings API - filters](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/email-settings/#manage_filters)

There is a [Java wrapper](https://developers.google.com/gdata/javadoc/com/google/gdata/client/appsforyourdomain/gmailsettings/GmailFilterService)

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Comment: @kleopatra thanks for the comment, will look to improve in future.